# Strange indent behaviour in (neo)vim with Python

Tags: python, vim, neovim

This issue is reproducible in vim and neovim. I'm using neovim with pretty much default values and no plugins (except the standard file plugins) and noticed a behavior that bothers me for a few years: In some situations vim gets the indenting wrong:

```py
def test():
    a = [<ENTER>
```

I'd expect the cursor on the next line to be here, e.g. 4 characters indented from the previous line:

```py
def test():
    a = [<ENTER>
        <HERE>
```

instead, vim consistently shifts by 8 characters and I end up here:

```py
def test():
    a = [<ENTER>
            <HERE>
```

This behavior is quite consistent in other situations too:

```py
def test():
    for i in range(10):
        a = [<ENTER>
                <HERE>
```

the cursor is shifted 8 characters instead of 4. My question is: where does that behavior come from and can it be fixed?

The relevant options set automatically by the python file plugin:

```
shiftround
softtabstop=4
tabstop=4
expandtab
shiftwidth=4

comments=b:#,fb:-
filetype=python
syntax=python
cinkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,!^F,o,O,e
commentstring=# %s
define=^\s*\(def\|class\)
include=^\s*\(from\|import\)
includeexpr=substitute(substitute(substitute(v:fname,b:grandparent_match,b:grandparent_sub,''),b:parent_match,b:parent_sub,''),b:child_match,b:child_sub,'g')
indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
indentkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,!^F,o,O,e,<:>,=elif,=except
```

Comment: In general, the default length of the tab key in the terminal is 8.

Comment: You may want to look at [cinoptions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+double+indent

Comment: See `:help ft-python-indent`.